# Using USA driver license on a different visa

Tags: usa, driving-licenses

I am about to travel to the USA on B1/B2 visa for a personal reason. I hold the valid USA driving license that was issued to me when I was in the USA on J1 visa 6 months back. The driver license is valid until December 2019.

I now stay outside USA. Can I use my US driver license now on B1/B2 visa?

Comment: It might not be valid. As I understand it, the driver license is supposed to be cancelled when you go out of status, but that might also depend on the state that issued it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton it definitely depends on the state.  I'm not actually aware of a state that cancels driver's licenses when immigration status lapses.  Do you have a source for the assertion "the driver license is supposed to be cancelled when you go out of status"?  The more likely cause of invalidity in my opinion is that the licensee is no longer a resident of the licensing state.  But even then, I would not be surprised if the license remains valid.

Comment: @phoog That is what I think. I have e-mailed Texas DPS. Let us see what happens.

Comment: @Oscar if there are any states where licenses are legally invalidated by lapsed immigration status, I would expect Texas to be among them.

Comment: Do you have a license from the country you are living in?  You should be able to use that in the US on a B1B2 visa

Comment: @Midavalo Unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the Texas DPS, one can drive as long as the driving license is unexpired. If a person had moved to another state, the license would have become invalid depending on the new state requirement.

It makes sense because one can drive outside USA using US driving license even if the person is no more resident of USA.